# Assert presence of a css class when the element is already selected with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs, ui-automation

Is there a way to assert the presence or absence of a css class given I have located the element through another class applied to it?

Here is a sample dom structure -

```
<div class="large-20 small-20 small-centered large-centered columns">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="divider1"></div>
      <input name="options" type="checkbox" value="2" class="selectable-options grid-value" />
    </div>
</div>
```

where the 'selectable-options' is the class that gets added to the element based on some conditions, and I would like to assert its presence or absence based on the workflow I am testing.
I use xpath to reach this element.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: I will update the question with some more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a css selector of an element and a class you want to check - you can simply combine them into one selector and check if such element exists with [casper.test.assertExists](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#assertexists)

```
var selector = ".some-element",
    className = "class-to-check"

// finding '.some-element.class-to-check'
casper.test.assertExists(selector + "." + className);
```

Or you can try [getElementInfo](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementinfo), it gives more info on target element

If you locate a needed element with css selector, the method returns object with the properties of the node. The class attribute is also available, so you'll be able to inspect a className string

```
casper.then(function(){
    var info = this.getElementInfo("#some-element");
    var className = info.attributes["class"] || "";
    this.test.assert(className.indexOf("class-to-check") > -1);
});
```